# Python seaborn line plot when i plot the x axis values are out of order (even though they are in order in dataframe)

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I'm using seaborn to do a line plot.

here's a sample data:

```
error_mean.head(5)
```

output is below:

```
    error_rate
10  0.829440
20  0.833747
30  0.835182
40  0.837922
50  0.835835
```

so the index values are indeed ordered (or at least it seems like).

here's my code plotting the above data:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
sns.lineplot(x=error_mean.index.values, y=error_mean['error_rate'])
```

and i keep getting a plot like following:
[image]

as you can see, the x-axis values are so out of order! i tried googling into this but i couldnt find similar issues answered.

appreciate any help!

Comment: what is printed when you print 'error_mean.index.values'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the issue is that error_mean.index.values is a Series of type `str`. You need to convert it as `int`.
Check the difference between:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as plt 

df1 = pd.DataFrame([
["10",  0.829440],
["20",  0.833747],
["100",  0.835182],
["40" , 0.837922],
["50", 0.835835]])

sns.lineplot(x=df1[0], y=df1[1])
```

and

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
["10",  0.829440],
["20",  0.833747],
["100",  0.835182],
["40" , 0.837922],
["50", 0.835835]])

sns.lineplot(x=(df1[0]).astype(int), y=df1[1])
```

So I will try:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
sns.lineplot(x=error_mean.index.values.astype(int), y=error_mean['error_rate'])
```

Comment: thank you! that's exactly it! i thought it would be int already. thank you so much